# Itunes doesn't want to dispose played podcasts

Tags: itunes, podcasts, macos

I have a Podcast settings: ‚Keep all unplayed episodes‘ but Itunes doesn't want to dispose those played ones. 
[image: 19 episodes to dispose]

There are only 9 new unplayed episodes and 19 fully played episodes are fully to dispose. But Itunes doesn't want to do it even if I try the refresh. 
I did also try to uncheck Default settings without change.

How to make Itunes to follow settings and keep only unplayed episodes on disk and dispose all those played?